# How Can I Get DNS Records from a List?

Tags: powershell, dns, record

I'm trying to get a list of DNS records on certain subnets. I can get the command to work for 1 or several subnets (by using `-like` and `-or`), but I will have 10+ subnets to get records for.

I tried adding a variable and tried to use this with `foreach` but it just returns an error `unexpected token in statement`. 
I feel like I may have this wrong on where this `foreach` statement is, but I'm not sure. 
This is a little above my head with nesting.

This is what I am able to get to work:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName zone.local -RRType A | 
   foreach ($subnet in $subnets) {
      where-object {$_.Recorddata.ipv4address -like $subnet}} | 
         where-object {$_.Recorddata.ipv4address -like "10.1.*.*" -or $_.Recorddata.ipv4address -like "192.168.*.*"} | 
            Select-Object HostName, RecordType ,@{Name='IPv4Address';Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}
   }
```

What I tried:

```
$subnets = get-content .\zonedata.txt

get-dnsserverresourcerecord -zonename "zone.local" -RRType A | 
   foreach ($subnet in $subnets) {
      where-object {$_.REcorddata.ipv4address -like $subnet}} |
         Select-Object HostName, RecordType ,@{Name='IPv4Address';Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}
   }
```

on the code that I am able to get to work, it returns all records within that zone, which is great, but like I said, I'm going to need this for 10+ different zones and I don't want to have to change the script for every zone and have different files for each zone.

Comment: Not quite sure what is the issue. If you have different files for zones you could add a zone name into the file or just name it after that zone.

Comment: I have a file that has 10+ different subnets listed. I'm trying to use that to find all records in just those subnets. i didnt want to keep changing the script and having it create a new file for each subnet.

Comment: You don't need to change the script. Add the subnet name as a first line in the file or name the file as the subnet. Then use that name in the script.

Comment: Use a CSV file, so you can map subnets to zones. For more assistance, I'd need to know if you have multiple subnets per zone, or if it is a one to one

Comment: @montonero - That isnt want I am asking to accomplish here.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Yeah I have a lot of different subnets in the zone. I'm trying to get dns entries based off a /16 subnet, so I will have, for example, subnets like 10.0.0.0, 10.1.0.0, 10.2.0.0., but I dont want to get say, 10.3.0.0 and 10.4.0.0.